# mocha fails to transpile react-native-i18n

Tags: mocha.js, react-native, babeljs

I'm working on testing react-native components, however when I run mocha with `babel-core` transpiler and this `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [ "react", "es2015", "stage-2" ]
}
```

I get:

```
let { Platform, NativeModules } = require('react-native')

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

This line lives in [react-native-i18n/index.js](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n/blob/master/index.js#L3)

I'm running mocha in harmony mode.

Comment: What version of babel-core are you using ? And what version of RN ?

Comment: RN 0.20.0-rc or 0.19 with babel-core 6.5.1 I found that this is probably due to the usage of native modules which node obviously fails to interpret

Comment: I had a a similar issue, on another package. I installed babel-preset-react-native `npm i babel-preset-react-native --save-dev` and added it to my .babelrc `"presets": ["stage-0", "react", "react-native"]` and it solved it. Maybe try it.